# How do I get Finder windows to reopen on start up?

Tags: macos, finder

I just got my new computer with system 10.7.2 and this is really bugging me. I like having a few Finder windows always open. When I shut down and then start up my computer the next day, all the windows I had opened in the Finder are closed save one. It always just has a single Finder window open. If I have 5 windows open when I shut down, I want all 5 of them open the next day. How do I make this happen? I can't stress this enough. The windows won't stay opened on restart.

In the general preferences I have the "Restore windows when quitting..." button checked. When I shut down, the "Reopen windows when logging back in" button always remains checked. I can find no other mention anywhere regarding windows maintenance and it's driving me nuts! This should be a no-brainer but I can't find any way of correcting this situation. It seems everywhere I look on-line, people are having the exact opposite problem.

Comment: I think this is a bug that needs to be fixed. I've even tried to delete the Finder preferences files and nothing changed. The Finder spaces options also doesn't stick.

Answer (score 11):

There might be several answers to that.

- Your restore for finder could be corrupted somehow. Delete the `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.finder.savedState` and give it a try
- Your finder app may be configured NOT to restore the windows. Try this: `defaults write com.apple.finder NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true`

Does your other apps have the same behaviour? Have you tried with another username to see how it goes?

Sources:

- http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/17/delete-specific-application-saved-states-from-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-resume/
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110722125937252